# How to replace None values in Python SQL Lite?

Tags: sqlite

I am working on the 8 Week SQL Challenge with the following data. I am using Python and SQL Lite.

```
c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS runner_orders')

c.execute('CREATE TABLE runner_orders (order_id INTEGER, runner_id INTEGER, pickup_time VARCHAR(19), distance VARCHAR(7), duration VARCHAR(10), cancellation VARCHAR(23))')

more_order2 = [ ('1', '1', '2020-01-01 18:15:34', '20km', '32 minutes', ''),
  ('2', '1', '2020-01-01 19:10:54', '20km', '27 minutes', ''),
  ('3', '1', '2020-01-03 00:12:37', '13.4km', '20 mins', 'NULL'),
  ('4', '2', '2020-01-04 13:53:03', '23.4', '40', 'NULL'),
  ('5', '3', '2020-01-08 21:10:57', '10', '15', 'NULL'),
  ('6', '3', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'Restaurant Cancellation'),
  ('7', '2', '2020-01-08 21:30:45', '25km', '25mins', 'null'),
  ('8', '2', '2020-01-10 00:15:02', '23.4 km', '15 minute', 'null'),
  ('9', '2', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'Customer Cancellation'),
  ('10', '1', '2020-01-11 18:50:20', '10km', '10minutes', 'null')]

c.executemany('INSERT INTO runner_orders VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', more_order2)

c.execute(query)

conn.commit()
```

I am trying to replace the '' values with null with this code:

```
query = '''
    UPDATE runner_orders
    SET cancellation = null
    WHERE cancellation IN ('NULL', '')
'''

c.execute(query)

query2 = '''
  SELECT * FROM runner_orders
    '''

for match in c.execute(query2):
    print(match)
```

For some reason, when I output the values, I got None in all the NULL spaces and it does not replace them with null. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`null` is not a string. SQL uses [trinary logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic): `true`, `false`, and `null`. SQL `null` roughly means "unknown" or "no value".

If you look at your table in the SQLite client you should see the value is `null`. Python is translating SQL `null` into the Python equivalent of [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None).